# Copying MSVCR120.dll when there is no access to System32 dll

Tags: .net, dll, wix, windows-installer, mosquitto

I installed mosquitto in my machine. I need to use the following command to start the exe.

```
mosquitto -v
```

When I type that, it says msvcr120.dll is missing. I'm installing this mosquitto through my application's setup. I've given dot net 4.5 as a pre-requisite. But I cannot manually copy the dll to the System32 folder in the machine being installed as I don't have access to that folder. I tried copying the dll to the mosquitto installation folder and running but it throws the below error.

[image]

What can I do to handle this situation? Whats the best way to put this dll through my WIX installer? The machine I'm trying to install is a newly installed Windows 8 machine that has dot net 4.5 installed. Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either include the C++ runtime merge-module in your WiX package. Or you can install the .DLL in the application folder. More information can be found here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293574.aspx